# Is it possible to wait until `.persist()` finishes caching in dask?

Tags: python, dask

Since `.persist()` caches data in the background, I'm wondering whether it is possible to wait until it finishes caching then do the following things. In addition, there is a way to have a progress bar for the caching process? Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the functions you're looking for are aptly named `wait` and `progress`.

```
from dask.distributed import wait, progress
```

The `progress` function takes any dask thing and renders a progress bar

```
>>> progress(x)
[XXXXXXX................]  5.2 seconds
```

If you are in the IPython notebook, then progress is also non-blocking and uses IPython widgets.  If you are in the IPython console or a straight Python executable, then `progress` is blocking and will not return until the computation completes.

If you do not want a progress bar, or if you are in the Jupyter notebook, then you may want to separately use the `wait` function, which will block until the computations finish.

```
wait(x)
```

http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.wait
http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.diagnostics.progress

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much or the help!